# Crash in QString toUtf8()

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, bad-alloc

I have a slot:

```
void Foo::func(QString str1, const QString& str2, int width, int height)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> _lock(m_mutex);

#ifdef _DEBUG
    MEMORYSTATUSEX statex;
    statex.dwLength = sizeof (statex);
    if (GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&statex)) {
        qDebug() << QString("There are %1 free MB of physical memory.\n").arg(statex.ullAvailPhys / 1024 / 1024);
    }
#endif

    BaseClass::someFunc(
        str1.toStdString(),
        str2.toUtf8().constData(),
        width,
        height
    );
}
```

It seems to be correct and it works. But if program works for a long time (night for example) it crashes in this function at line

```
str2.toUtf8().constData()
```

I first thought that this is a thread-based error, but my lock didn't work. All the local variables and class members are ok. The crash error is:

```
First-chance exception at 0x76E45B68 foo.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x00EFC6EC
```

But from the code above last **MEMORYSTATUSEX** show that available memory is

```
There are 2314 free MB of physical memory
```

I also thought that **str2** is too big, but it works fine with length of 49152, 168441 etc. What is the problem? Did I miss something?

Stack Trace:

```
    KernelBase.dll!_RaiseException@16()    Unknown
[External Code] 
Qt5Cored.dll!qBadAlloc() Line 2849  C++
Qt5Cored.dll!QByteArray::QByteArray(int size, Qt::Initialization __formal) Line 1409    C++
Qt5Cored.dll!QUtf8::convertFromUnicode(const QChar * uc, int len) Line 151  C++
Qt5Cored.dll!QString::toUtf8_helper(const QString & str) Line 4373  C++
Qt5Cored.dll!QString::toUtf8() Line 56  C++
foo.exe!Foo::func(QString str1, const QString & str2, int width, int height) Line 3600  C++
foo.exe!Foo::qt_static_metacall(QObject * _o, QMetaObject::Call _c, int _id, void * * _a) Line 1126 C++
Qt5Cored.dll!QMetaObject::activate(QObject * sender, int signalOffset, int local_signal_index, void * * argv) Line 3717 C++
Qt5Cored.dll!QMetaObject::activate(QObject * sender, const QMetaObject * m, int local_signal_index, void * * argv) Line 3582    C++
foo.exe!SomeClass::func(QString _t1, const QString & _t2, int _t3, int _t4) Line 137    C++
foo.exe!SomeClass::qt_static_metacall(QObject * _o, QMetaObject::Call _c, int _id, void * * _a) Line 81 C++
Qt5Cored.dll!QMetaCallEvent::placeMetaCall(QObject * object) Line 485   C++
Qt5Cored.dll!QObject::event(QEvent * e) Line 1246   C++
Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject * receiver, QEvent * e) Line 3720    C++
Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QApplication::notify(QObject * receiver, QEvent * e) Line 3164  C++
Qt5Cored.dll!QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject * receiver, QEvent * event) Line 935  C++
Qt5Cored.dll!QCoreApplication::sendEvent(QObject * receiver, QEvent * event) Line 228   C++
Qt5Cored.dll!QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents(QObject * receiver, int event_type, QThreadData * data) Line 1552    C++
Qt5Cored.dll!QCoreApplication::sendPostedEvents(QObject * receiver, int event_type) Line 1410   C++
qwindowsd.dll!QWindowsGuiEventDispatcher::sendPostedEvents() Line 81    C++
Qt5Cored.dll!qt_internal_proc(HWND__ * hwnd, unsigned int message, unsigned int wp, long lp) Line 414   C++
[External Code] 
Qt5Cored.dll!QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents(QFlags<enum QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag> flags) Line 807    C++
qwindowsd.dll!QWindowsGuiEventDispatcher::processEvents(QFlags<enum QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag> flags) Line 73   C++
Qt5Cored.dll!QEventLoop::processEvents(QFlags<enum QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag> flags) Line 129   C++
Qt5Cored.dll!QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<enum QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag> flags) Line 204    C++
Qt5Cored.dll!QCoreApplication::exec() Line 1188 C++
Qt5Guid.dll!QGuiApplication::exec() Line 1508   C++
Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QApplication::exec() Line 2957  C++
foo.exe!WinMain(HINSTANCE__ * __formal, HINSTANCE__ * __formal, char * lpCmdLine, int __formal) Line 348    C++
[External Code]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: May be the problem is memory fragmentation? You may have `2314 free MB` in total, but for example that memory chunks with length < 1K, then you can not 40K chunk for string.

Comment: Btw, using such constructions like `str2.toUtf8().constData()` is very bad practice, because you are returning a pointer to internals of temporary objects. So `str2.toUtf8().constData()` will be invalid instantly after `BaseClass::someFunc` call. So if you will pass it somewhere you will get problems

Comment: Well, I'll check memory-fragmentation moment and write result here later.

Comment: What happens if you make str2 a plain QString instead of a const reference? Could it be that the string passed as str2 is altered somewhere else concurrently?

Comment: I thought about this and already tried but if I do that, the behavior will be the same. (I just forgot to write about this)

Comment: This problem might have been reported about half a decade ago but it still rears its ugly head.  Does anyone know potential root causes of this crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who, like me, just stumbled on this thread because they wanted to convert a `QString` into a `char *` with a call to `str.toUtf8().constData()` or `str.toUtf8().data()`, but that was leading a program to crash or to throw an exception like `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on XCode, here's the answer:

- in a call like `foo = str.toUtf8().constData();`, the `str.toUtf8()` part creates a temp object.
- a call to `tmp.data()` or `tmp.constData()` return a pointer to an internal buffer managed by the object itself, and whose lifetime is tied to the temp object's lifetime. [source](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#data).
- once that statement is executed, the lifetime of the object whose address was assigned to `foo`, once returned by `data()` or `constData()`, will end.
- therefore, as expected, after that statement `foo` will hold an address to an object whose lifetime ended, thus causing crashes and exceptions.